# Use regular expression to fetch 3 groups from string

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my expected result.

Input a string and get three returned string.

I have no idea how to finish it with Regex in Ruby.

this is my roughly  idea.

```
match(/(.*?)(_)(.*?)(\d+)/)
```

## Input and expected output

```
# "R224_OO2003" => R224, OO, 2003
# "R2241_OOP2003" => R2244, OOP, 2003
```

Comment: Is the second result a typo? R2244 instead of R2241?

Comment: Will the pattern always be: everything before "_" is group 1, the two repeated characters after "_" is group 2, and any digits after that in a row are group 3?

Comment: Why haven't you answered @Beartech's questions?  If there is a typo, please edit your question and fix it. You need to also say in words what the criteria is for splitting the string into three pieces (again, by editing the question). For example, this is one possible interpretation: "The string contains exactly one underscore. The first of the three strings is everything preceding the underscore. The third string is the last four characters, which represents a year.  The second string is everything between the first and third strings, excluding the underscore."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example description I gave in my comment on the question is correct, you need a very straightforward regex:

```
r = /(.+)_(.+)(\d{4})/
```

Then:

```
"R224_OO2003".scan(r).flatten   #=> ["R224",   "OO", "2003"]  
"R2241_OOP2003".scan(r).flatten #=> ["R2241", "OOP", "2003"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your pattern covers all possibilities, then you just need to use the match object to return the 3 strings:

```
my_match = "R224_OO2003".match(/(.*?)(_)(.*?)(\d+)/)
    #=>  #<MatchData "R224_OO2003" 1:"R224" 2:"_" 3:"OO" 4:"2003">
puts my_match[0] #=> "R224_OO2003"
puts my_match[1] #=> "R224"
puts my_match[2] #=> "_"
puts my_match[3] #=> "00"
puts my_match[4] #=> "2003"
```

A MatchData object contains an array of each match group starting at index [1]. As you can see, index [0] returns the entire string. If you don't want the capture the "_" you can leave it's parentheses out.

Also, I'm not sure you are getting what you want with the part:

(.*?)

this basically says one or more of any single character followed by zero or one of any single character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your three parts consist of (R and one or more digits), then an underbar, then (one or more non-whitespace characters), before finally (a 4-digit numeric date), then your regex could be something like this:

```
^(R\d+)_(\S+)(\d{4})$
```

The ^ indicates start of string, and the $ indicates end of string. \d+ indicates one or more digits, while \S+ says one or more non-whitespace characters.  The \d{4} says exactly four digits.

To recover data from the matches, you could either use the pre-defined globals that line up with your groups, or you could could use named captures.

To use the match globals just use $1, $2, and $3.  In general, you can figure out the number to use by counting the left parentheses of the specific group.

To use the named captures, include ? right after the left paren of a particular group.  For example:

```
x = "R2241_OOP2003"
match_data = /^(?<first>R\d+)_(?<second>\S+)(?<third>\d{4})$/.match(x)
puts match_data['first'], match_data['second'], match_data['third']
```

yields

```
R2241
OOP
2003
```

as expected.

Comment: For what it is worth on the original question, I try to avoid using .* as much as possible.  If you're not very careful, it can often get you into trouble.  Additionally, (.*?) isn't much of anything... For example, I can substitute `/(.*)_(.*)(\d+)/` (in other words drop the question marks) and get same result.  ? is used to indicate 0 or 1 of the preceding element while . means any character and * means 0 or more.  So .*? is 0 or more of anything 0 or 1 times.  You get the same effect with just plain .*

Comment: Daniel, regarding `(.*)` versus `(.*?)`, yes, either can be used here (provided there is just one underscore), but you may have left the impression that the two expressions always have the same effect, which is not the case. For example, suppose `s = 'a_b_c'`, then `s.scan /(.*)_(.*)/ #=> [["a_b", "c"]]`, whereas `s.scan /(.*?)_(.*)/ #=> [["a", "b_c"]]`.